# If a random variable $X$ is measurable with respect to the tail $\sigma$-algebra, then it is constant a.s.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider Kolmogorov's Zero-One law:

> Suppose that $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independent
>   random variables. Then any event belonging to the tail
>   $\sigma$-algebra $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$
>   has probability $0$ or $1$.

Now the book says:

> Every random variable $X$ which is measurable with respect to the tail
>   $\sigma$-algebra is a.s. constant.

I do not quite see this, but I think it should be easy. So since $X$ is measurable with respect to the tail $\sigma$-algebra, we have that $$\{X \leq t\} \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Similarly also $\{X \geq t\}$. So by $$\{X = t\} = \{X \leq t\} \cap \{X \geq t\}$$ we get that $P(X = t)$ is either $0$ or $1$. **Why should it be $1$ for some $t$?** Or how does one see this?

Comment: The usual approach is to note that the CDF $F_X$ takes only the calues $0$ and $1$. Being nondecreasing with limits $0$ at $-\infty$ and $1$ at $+\infty$, the function $F_X$ must jump from $0$ to $1$ at the point $$x=\sup\{t\mid F_X(t)=0\}=\inf\{t\mid F_X(t)=1\}$$ that is, $$P(X=x)=\lim_{u\to0,u>0}F(x+u)-F(x-u)=1-0=1$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also find that $F_X(t)=P(X\leq t)\in\{0,1\}$ for each $t$.

Combining this with $\lim_{t\to\infty}F_X(t)=1$ we will arrive at $F_X(t)=1$ for some $t$.

Now let $t_0:=\inf\{t\in\mathbb R\mid F(t)=1\}$.

Then $t_0\in\mathbb R$ and you can find that $P(X=t_0)=1$.

Comment: Nice and clear. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome.